# How does docker map host partitions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, containers

I'm relatively new to docker, and when I started a container (an ubuntu base image), I noticed the following:

On the host,

```
$ df -h
...
/dev/sdc1       180M   98M   70M  59% /boot
/dev/sdc2        46G   20G   24G  46% /home
/dev/sdc5        37G  7.7G   27G  23% /usr
/dev/sdc6        19G   13G  5.3G  70% /var

$ lsblk
...
sdc      8:32   0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0   190M  0 part /boot
├─sdc2   8:34   0  46.6G  0 part /home
├─sdc3   8:35   0  18.6G  0 part /
├─sdc4   8:36   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdc5   8:37   0  37.3G  0 part /usr
├─sdc6   8:38   0  18.6G  0 part /var
├─sdc7   8:39   0  29.8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sdc8   8:40   0  42.8G  0 part
```

On the container

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           19G   13G  5.3G  70% /
none             19G   13G  5.3G  70% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdc6        19G   13G  5.3G  70% /etc/hosts
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /proc/kcore
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /proc/latency_stats
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /proc/timer_stats

$ lsblk
sdc      8:32   0 232.9G  0 disk 
|-sdc1   8:33   0   190M  0 part 
|-sdc2   8:34   0  46.6G  0 part 
|-sdc3   8:35   0  18.6G  0 part 
|-sdc4   8:36   0     1K  0 part 
|-sdc5   8:37   0  37.3G  0 part 
|-sdc6   8:38   0  18.6G  0 part /var/lib/cassandra
|-sdc7   8:39   0  29.8G  0 part [SWAP]
`-sdc8   8:40   0  42.8G  0 part
```

**Question 1**: why is `sdc6` mounted on different places between the host and the container?

Because the contents of the two mount points are different, so I assume docker must have done some kind of device mapping on the container, so `sdc6` in the container isn't the same as the one on the host.  However, the partition capacity and usage are the same, so I'm confused here.

**Question 2**: why is the container's root dir usage so high?  The docker image doesn't have much stuff on it.

Thanks for any help.

**Addition**

The Dockerfile has a line

```
VOLUME /var/lib/cassandra
```

Comment: Sounds like something that's a better fit for AskUbuntu or Superuser than Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question 1: why is sdc6 mounted on different places between the host and the container?

`/dev/sdc6` on your host is `/var`, which is where `/var/lib/docker` resides and where Docker keeps certain data, such as the `hosts` file allocated to your container.

The `hosts` file is exposed as a bind mount inside the container, which is why you see:

```
/dev/sdc6        19G   13G  5.3G  70% /etc/hosts
```

> Question 2: why is the container's root dir usage so high? The docker image doesn't have much stuff on it.

Take a look at the `df` output inside the container:

```
rootfs           19G   13G  5.3G  70% /
```

Now look at the `df` output on your host, and you'll see:

```
/dev/sdc6        19G   13G  5.3G  70% /var
```

The `df` inside the container is reflecting the state of the host filesystem.  This suggests that you are using the `aufs` or `overlay` storage driver, both of which create "overlay" filesystems for containers on top of the host filesystem.  The output from `df` would look different if you were using the `devicemapper` storage driver, relies on device mapper block devices instead of overlay filesystems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Isn't `/etc/hosts` the hostname-ip mapping file?  Why is /dev/sdc6 mounted to that?

Comment: The `hosts` file (which, yes, is the hostname-ip mapping file) is created by Docker, and it lives in `/var/lib/docker`, which is on `/dev/sdc6`.  This file is bind-mounted into the container (as in `mount --bind /some/file /some/other/path`), which is why you see `/dev/sdc6` in the `df` output.